# Convert Bitmap to Array and send the Array via Networkstream

Tags: c#, arrays, networking, bitmap, byte

I have a problem in my code. It's about a chat program where you can take a screenshot from the other PC. I got the code below. But if I run the code the screenshot Looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKvkd.png). The problem is that I don't receive all of the bytes of the image (truncated). There's must be something wrong with the client (sender) and the server (receiver).

---

## Code:

**Client: (send)**:

```
                        string ip = "192.168.98.78";
                        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
                        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
                        Console.WriteLine("taking screenshot");
                        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, b.Size);
                        g.Dispose();
                        
                                                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                        b.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                        byte[] bmp = ms.ToArray();
                        
                        Console.WriteLine("sending pic");
                        do {
                            try
                            {
                                TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(ip, 2000);
                            NetworkStream clientSockStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                                Console.WriteLine("connecting to server");
                                StreamWriter clientStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(clientSockStream);
                                Console.WriteLine("send data");
                                
                                    clientSockStream.Write(bmp, 0, 1024);
                                
                                tcpClient.Close();
                                fertig = true;
                            } catch (Exception h)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(h.Message);
                            }
                            
                        } while (fertig != true);
```

**Server: (receiver)**

```
 Console.WriteLine("");
                            
                            TcpListener tcpServerListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 2000);
                            tcpServerListener.Start();
                        try
                        {
                            Socket serverSocket = tcpServerListener.AcceptSocket();

                            NetworkStream serverSocketStream = new NetworkStream(serverSocket);


                            Console.WriteLine("SERVER");
                            tcpServerListener.Start();



                            Console.WriteLine("[connected to client]");
                            
                            byte[] byt = new byte[1024];
                            Console.WriteLine("-");
                            serverSocketStream.Read(byt, 0, 1024);



                            Console.WriteLine("[-]");
                            Console.WriteLine("write bytes");
                            File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\users\jakob\desktop\bild1.jpg", byt);
                        } catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                            tcpServerListener.Stop();
                        do
                        {
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hey, i told you that the Picture i receve isnt  the full one.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKvkd.png

Comment: @jakob you have a correct Answer. Mark as solution by clicking the `✔` 
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit:

---

I found a solution for '"The specified argument is outside the range of valid values."' the problem. Try this!

```
                    serverSocketStream.Read(byt, 0, 1024); // Get the file size
                    byte[] byt_2 = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byt)) + 300];
                    Console.WriteLine("-");
                    serverSocketStream.Read(byt_2, 0, byt_2.Length); // Get The File
                    Console.WriteLine("-");
                    Console.WriteLine("write bytes");
                    File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\users\jakob\desktop\bild1.jpg", byt_2);
```

---

**You're Code to Receive:**

```
byte[] byt = new byte[1024];
Console.WriteLine("-");
serverSocketStream.Read(byt, 0, 1024);
```

You decided to read the image by storing in a byte array capable of holding 1024 bytes. You'll need more than 1024 bytes because the image that you are trying to send is more than 1024 bytes. You can solve this problem by sending the file size first, then sending the picture. Take a look at this:

**Proper Code to Send:** (Disapproved)

```
                    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
                    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
                    Console.WriteLine("taking screenshot");
                    g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, b.Size);
                    g.Dispose();
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    b.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                    byte[] bmp = ms.ToArray();


                    // Send the file size
                    clientSockStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bmp.Length), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bmp.Length).Length);


                   // Send the file:
                 
                   clientSockStream.Write(bmp, 0, bmp.Length);
```

**Proper Code To Receive:** (Disapproved)

```
                   byte[] byt = new byte[1024];
                   serverSocketStream.Read(byt, 0, 1024); // Get the file size

                   byte[] byt_2 = new byte[byt.Length+300];
                   serverSocketStream.Read(byt, 0, byt_2.Length); // Get The File

                   File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\users\jakob\desktop\bild1.jpg", byt_2);
```

---

I haven't test this code, but if you have any error, you can ask in the comment, and I'll try to fix it!

Comment: I tested the Code from @Adola there is a Problem "cant convert int to char[] "

Comment: I have another solution.

Comment: what are the using directories you are jousing in the Code above?

Comment: @jakob Using System; Using System.Net; Using System.Net.Sockets; Using System.IO; Using System,Text ---- Is that what you're asking?

Comment: clientSockStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bmp.Length), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bmp.Length).Length); this line isnt working every time im trying to run this code

Answer (score 0):

i solved the Problems

send:

```
                                TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(ip, 2000);
                                NetworkStream clientSockStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                                Console.WriteLine("connecting to server");
                                StreamWriter clientStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(clientSockStream);
                                Console.WriteLine("send data");
                                //-
                                Bitmap b = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
                                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
                                Console.WriteLine("taking screenshot");
                                g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, b.Size);
                                g.Dispose();
                                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                                b.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                                byte[] bmp = ms.ToArray();
                                // Send the file size
                                sw.WriteLine(bmp.Length);
                                // Send the file
                                clientSockStream.Write(bmp, 0, bmp.Length);
                                //-
                                tcpClient.Close();
```

receive:

```
                            Socket serverSocket = tcpServerListener.AcceptSocket();
                            NetworkStream serverSocketStream = new NetworkStream(serverSocket);
                            Console.WriteLine("SERVER");
                            tcpServerListener.Start();
                            Console.WriteLine("[connected to client]");
                            byte[] byt = new byte[1024];
                            //get size Lenght
                            int Lenght = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());
                            byte[] byt_2 = new byte[Lenght + 3000];
                            Console.WriteLine("-");
                            // Get The File
                            serverSocketStream.Read(byt_2, 0, byt_2.Length);
                            Console.WriteLine("-");
                            Console.WriteLine("write bytes");
                            //write bytes in the file
                            File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\users\jakob\desktop\bild1.jpg", byt_2);
```

Comment: You can mark my post as an answer by clicking the 'v' sign :)

Answer (score -2):

i solved the Problem i had with the Code from adola like this

send:

```
                                Bitmap b = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
                                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
                                Console.WriteLine("taking screenshot");
                                g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, b.Size);
                                g.Dispose();

                                b.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                                byte[] bmp = ms.ToArray();
                                string kl = Convert.ToString(bmp);

                                // Send the file size
                                Char[] ch = new Char[bmp.Length]; //added
                                clientSockStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ch), 0,Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(ch));


                                // Send the file:

                                clientSockStream.Write(bmp, 0, bmp.Length);
```

but now this Code sas "The specified argument is outside the range of valid values."
Could some one tell me where the Problem is?

receive:

```
                                serverSocketStream.Read(byt, 0, 1024); // Get the file size
                            byte[] byt_2 = new byte[byt.Length + 300];
                            Console.WriteLine("-");
                            serverSocketStream.Read(byt, 0, byt_2.Length); // Get The File
                            Console.WriteLine("-");
                            Console.WriteLine("write bytes");
                            File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\users\jakob\desktop\bild1.jpg", byt_2);
```

Comment: I changed and edit my answer, take a look at it again. I post a new solution!